# Set wallpaper in Headless JS react native background task

Tags: android, react-native, background-process

I have a scenario in which I want to change the wallpaper on android device every hour. E.g show a bright wallpaper in early mornings and later hours show dimmed colored wallpapers. I want to fetch new wallpapers every hour in the back ground and set it even if the app is in the background or terminated by the user.

According to the react native docs it states

> You can do anything in your task such as network requests, timers and so on, as long as it doesn't touch UI.

I gather it's clear I can make network request in the background and fetch new wallpapers, but is using Set Wallpaper in Android considered touching the UI?